# Issue with calling GraphSage Neo4j graph embedding method from python driver

Tags: python, java, neo4j, cypher

I try to call **GraphSage Neo4j GDS** method using **python**. The goal is to perform nodes embedding of an in-memory projected graph. I runned this part of the code:

```
query = """CALL gds.beta.graphSage.train(
  'ExperimentsConditionNeighborhood',
  {
    modelName: 'multiLabelModel1',
    featureProperties: ['final_prot_interet', 'pH', 'temperature', 'glucose'],
    projectedFeatureDimension: 22,
    embeddingDimension: 4,
    randomSeed: 19,
    searchDepth: 2,
    epochs: 25,
   learningrate: 0.001,
   batchSize:30,
   aggregator: 'MEAN',
   sampleSizes: [25, 10],
   activationFunction: 'ReLu',
   tolerance: 1e-5
  }
)"""

conn.query(query, db=db)
```

I got the following error:

```
Query failed: {code: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed} {message: Failed to invoke procedure `gds.beta.graphSage.train`: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No more running tasks}
```

Any help on that ?

I found some answers in Java framework, since the error seems to be generated by the Neo4J JVM. But in my case I need a fix on python.

Just a remark:
This error message does not appear when I reduce the number of featureProperties.

Comment: Are all of your properties type float or list or float? Do they all exist in the graph with that capitalization?